# Finding the mean of adjacent elements (row and column) in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an image from which I have created a DataFrame based on its pixel intensity. From this, I would like to create a grid where I find the mean intensity within each square in that grid, represented by 2x2 pixels. This will be done in order to capture larger areas of intensities, in order to distinguish them from background noise. (I thought it would be good to include this in order to provide context.)

In the DataFrame, this would translate into finding the mean of 4 values from a group of 2 adjacent rows and columns.

So, to illustrate the problem, let's say we have the following DataFrame:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':(np.linspace(1,4,num=4)),'B':(np.linspace(5,8,num=4)),'C':(np.linspace(9,12,num=4)), 'D':(np.linspace(13,16,num=4))})
```

From that, we want to create a DataFrame that corresponds to the mean of each square. In this case, it would correspond to the following (i.e. for example, 3 would be the mean of the 2x2 square with the values (1,5,2,6), 11.5 would be the mean of (9, 13, 10, 14):

```
df_mean=DataFrame({'A':pd.Series([3,11.5]),'B':pd.Series([5.5,13.5])})
```

If the question is still unclear, imagine taking the original DataFrame and drawing a vertical line and a horizontal line across the middle. This would thus yield 4 boxes. Within each of the 4 boxes you will find 4 values. I would like to calculate the mean of each box and insert it onto a new DataFrame that consists of the means of the boxes.

PS: Unfortunately, I do not yet know how to display the DataFrames themselves, rather than just the code. The print function didn't work. I hope that is not too bothersome.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this very efficiently using the underlying `numpy` array:

```
def square_mean(arr, y, x):
    yy, xx = arr.shape
    vals = arr.reshape(y, yy//y, x, xx//x).mean((1,3))
    return vals

pd.DataFrame(square_mean(df.values, 2, 2))
```

```
     0     1
0  3.5  11.5
1  5.5  13.5
```

---

This solution works all because of some clever reshaping of the array, here is how the reshaping works:

```
yy, xx = arr.shape
vals = arr.reshape(2, yy//2, 2, xx//2)
print(vals)
```

```
[[[[ 1.  5.]
   [ 9. 13.]]

  [[ 2.  6.]
   [10. 14.]]]


 [[[ 3.  7.]
   [11. 15.]]

  [[ 4.  8.]
   [12. 16.]]]]
```

As you can see, the array has been reshaped into chunks, that we can then use to calculate the mean.

---

This solution will scale to all input sizes, simply select `x` as the number of chunks along the x-axis, and `y` for the number of chunks along the y-axis:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 5, (10, 10)))

   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  1  3  4  2  3  3  3  2  1  2
1  3  3  4  1  3  4  4  4  1  3
2  2  3  2  2  4  4  1  1  1  1
3  1  2  1  2  1  3  1  1  2  3
4  2  2  3  4  3  2  4  3  4  2
5  3  3  1  4  2  1  2  3  1  3
6  2  1  3  4  3  2  3  4  3  4
7  2  3  4  2  1  1  1  1  3  2
8  4  3  2  2  2  2  2  1  3  3
9  3  2  1  2  1  3  4  2  4  4
```

We can divide into any number of chunks:

```
square_mean(df.values, 2, 2)
```

```
array([[2.44, 2.4 ],
       [2.4 , 2.48]])

square_mean(df.values, 5, 5)
```

```
array([[2.5 , 2.75, 3.25, 3.25, 1.75],
       [2.  , 1.75, 3.  , 1.  , 1.75],
       [2.5 , 3.  , 2.  , 3.  , 2.5 ],
       [2.  , 3.25, 1.75, 2.25, 3.  ],
       [3.  , 1.75, 2.  , 2.25, 3.5 ]])
```

Comment: This is a very clever solution

Answer (score 0):

Just use a convolution on the underlying numpy array:

```
import scipy.ndimage
full_conv = scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve(df.values, 0.25*np.ones((2,2)))
strided_conv = full_conv[::2, ::2]
```

Result:

```
array([[ 3.5, 11.5],
       [ 5.5, 13.5]])
```

Comment: I'm getting a `data type not understood` error for the second line, seems to have to do with the weights you've given to the convolution

Comment: @user3483203 Oops. Accidentally deleted some parentheses when I simplified the code. Fixed it, thanks!